# Get vector<Point2f> from cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I am getting an input of vector of 2d points, make transformation on them and then output transformed vector of 2d points. My code needs to run fast so I want to optimize memory access time, is there a way to cast rotated_points to vector without copying the data?

```
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> points =
        std::vector<cv::Point2f>({{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}});
    auto points_mat= cv::Mat(points);
    auto rotation_matrix = cv::Matx22f({1, 2, 3, 4});
    cv::Mat rotated_points;
    cv::transform(points_mat, rotated_points, rotation_matrix);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> res_vec;
    res_vec.assign(rotated_points.begin<cv::Point2f>(), rotated_points.end<cv::Point2f>());
```

I tried to execute the code without copying the data

Comment: Can you try to feed std::vector<cv::Point2f> directly to the cv::transform destination/output? Imho that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> res_vec(points.size());
cv::Mat rotated_points(res_vec);
cv::transform(points_mat, rotated_points, rotation_matrix);
```

Create `vector` and pass it as argument to `cv::Mat` instance with `copyData` flag set to false (by default it is false [cv::Mat ctor](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a23b182c4ffd46abe38f460c1480ae887)). `cv::Mat`
will just refer to vector data as underlying data - `cv::Mat` will share passed vector's data. All results generated by `cv::transform` will
be stored inside vector by `cv::Mat` interface.